# Invalid character statement case value in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement, character

My code is telling me that the case 'A+' is an invalid character statement, but I need to be able to have case A+, A, A- and so on. What I'm wondering is: can I not have + or - inside the case value at all? and if so, is there any other way to identify what the user inputs into the console. I haven't been able to find an answer browsing around. Help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeAdvice {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    // User will input grade and program will give advice corresponding 
    // to that grade

    // Prompt use for their grade
    System.out.println("What was your grade on the midterm?");

    char midtermGrade;

    // Create an input object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    midtermGrade = input.next().charAt(0);

    // Determine which advice to give based on grade
    switch (midtermGrade)
    {
        case 'A+' : 
        case 'a+' : System.out.println("Continue doing what you have been doing, ask questions"); 
            break;
        default: System.out.println("This grade is invalid.");
            break;

}
    // Close input
    input.close();
}

}
```

Comment: You need to use **double quotes** for a `String`. Single quotes are reserved solely for `char`.

Comment: 7 answers in 6 minutes. Bravo, Stack Overflow. Never ceases to amaze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character literals in Java identify one character, not multiple characters, within single-quotes.  For multiple characters, you must use a `String`, delimited by double-quote characters.

In Java 7+, you can use `String`s as case labels, e.g.

```
case "A+":
```

But you are only using the first character of input.  Change

```
char midtermGrade;
midtermGrade = input.next().charAt(0);
```

to

```
String midtermGrade;
midtermGrade = input.next();
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please indicate how you think this answer can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` can hold a single character. Instead, you could just use a `String`:

```
String midtermGrade;

// Create an input object
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
midtermGrade = input.next();

// Determine which advice to give based on grade
switch (midtermGrade)
{
    // Note that strings are denoted by "s, not 's.
    case "A+" : 
    case "a+" : System.out.println("Continue doing what you have been doing, ask questions"); 
        break;
    default: System.out.println("This grade is invalid.");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String`, and normalize the case

```
switch( input.next().toUpperCase() )
{
    case "A+" :
        ...
    default :
        ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`"A+"`, double quotes for string, single quote for character.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are using a character instead of a string. A character is exactly what it says, one character. A+ is two characters A and +. Use double quotes (") for string literals. For example:

```
'A' \\ This is a character
"A" \\ This is a string
```

Answer (score -1):

"A+" is not char , it is string define it as string .

Answer (score -4):

A+ is a string, not a character. You could've done this in C# (using " rather than '), but not in Java, nor most other languages. Simplest way out for you is probably to convert the switch into a series of 'if' statements.

Comment: You can switch on a `String` in Java.